# adding a click count to a react native

Tags: react-native

So I am building an app that I want to implement basically a 'like' button on and I can't seem to get the right combination of things to make it work. Basically I want to press a like button and have a number on the page that shows how many times it has been liked. Anyone have any ideas? This is what I have so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View, Image,TouchableOpacity,Text, StatusBar, 
ScrollView } from 'react-native';


export default class SingleVeg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
console.log("Here", props);
      this.state = {
        data: {},
        count: 0
      }
      this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }

  update() {
       this.setState({ count: this.state.data.count + 1 })
     }

async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://just-
ripe.herokuapp.com/vegetable/$ 
{this.props.navigation.state.params.id}`)
  const json = await response.json()
    this.setState({data: json})

}

render(){
console.log(typeof this.state.data, this.state.data.id)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.image}>
        <Image
        style ={{ width: 350, height: 200
        }}
        source={require("../../images/JustRipe.png")}/>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.data.title}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.love} onPress ={this.update}>
<Text style= {styles.loveText}>Love: {this.state.data.count}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your update function, it should be:

```
 update() {
   this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
 }
```

vs. `this.state.data.count`

You should also update your text to read from count. ie.

```
Love: {this.state.count}
```

and when you save state:

```
this.setState({data: json, count: json.count})
```

Comment: Please mention, to change this way he need to change `Love: {this.state.data.count}` to `Love: {this.state.count}` and when he get data he need to: `this.setState({data: json, count: json.count})`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have 2 `count` storage.

Remove `count` in state:

```
this.state = {
  data: {},
  count: 0
}
```

And update correct count in data:

```
this.setState({ data: { ...data, count: this.state.data.count + 1 }})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'`enter code here`;

class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  }

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count - 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Counter</h2>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
          <span>{this.state.count}</span>
          <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter;
```